# Re render child component depending on child action while passing data to parent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Parent Component where I make an Ajax call to hydrate two children Components. C1 only needs the data once, C2 actually is able to get more data through additional Ajax calls and will be re render adequately .

It is way easier for me to make the Ajax Call in my Parent Component. But then I can't figure out how to 'get more data' in C2, pass that data in Parent and finally re render C2 only. I had many tries through callbacks (you can see it in the code), lifting state up etc, I am unable to do it. I don't know what to do with useEffect either...

Some code :

```
const Reviews: FunctionComponent = () => { 
    let variables = {
        offset: 0,
        limit: 2,
        filter: filter,
        order: order
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect called");
    });

    const {data: dataReviews, loading: loadingReviews, error: errorReviews} = useQuery(GetReviews, {
        ssr: false,
        variables: variables
    });

    function parentCallback(offset: number, limit: number) {
        variables.offset = offset;
        variables.limit = limit;
    }

    if (!loadingReviews && !errorReviews && dataReviews) {
        let reviews = !loadingReviews && !errorReviews && dataReviews ? dataReviews.reviews[0] : null;
        const stats = reviews.stats;

        reviews = reviews.reviews;

        return (
            <div className={`${styles.netreviews_review_rate_and_stars}`}>
                <ReviewsSideInfo stats={stats}
                                 total={getRecommandation(stats).total}
                                 recommandation={getRecommandation(stats).percentageRecommandation}
                />
                <ReviewsContainer parentCallback={parentCallback} reviews={reviews}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
    return (<div></div>);
}
export default Reviews;
```

As you can see `<ReviewsSideInfo/>` (C1) relies on that Ajax call (using `stats` object), and so does `<ReviewsContainer />` (C2), but in C2 -> :

```
const ReviewsContainer: FunctionComponent<ReviewsContainerProps> = ({reviews, parentCallback}) => {
    const [{offset, limit}, setReviews] = useState({offset: 0, limit: 3});
        
    return (
        <div className={`${styles.right_block}`}>
            <div className={`${styles.reviews_list}`}>

                <Fragment>
                    {reviews.map((element, i) => {
                        return (
                            <div>
                                <div key={i}>
                                    <Review rate={element.rate}
                                            firstname={element.firstname}
                                            lastname={element.lastname}
                                            review={element.review}
                                     />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                    <button onClick={() => {
                        setReviews({offset: 0, limit: limit + 3});
                        parentCallback(0, limit + 3)
                    }}>
                        <FormattedMessage id="load-more"/></button>
                </Fragment>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

-> I need to be able to load more data.
Sorry for the long piece of code. How can I achieve that ? I know useReducer may be of help but it seems even more difficult to me since I'm new to React.

*Last thing : in C1, I need to be able to filter that data (per rating) so I need to find a way to communicate through all these components... same problem actually.*

**EDIT**: I could have updated the state in Parent component but then the whole component would refresh and that's not what I want (already tried that)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try wrapping your component with

```
React.memo(your component)
```

I will look something like below:

```
const MemoisedComponent = React.memo(ReviewsSideInfo);




<div className={`${styles.netreviews_review_rate_and_stars}`}>
                <MemoisedComponent stats={stats}
                                 total={getRecommandation(stats).total}
                                 recommandation={getRecommandation(stats).percentageRecommandation}
                />
                <ReviewsContainer parentCallback={parentCallback} reviews={reviews}/>
            </div>
```

Also in

```
parentCallback(offset,limit) {
setOffset(offset)
setLimit(limit)
}
```

below useEffect will only be called when the offset and limit value is changed.

```
useEffect(() => {
//api call logic 
},[offset,limit]);
```

below is how your state should look like:

```
const [offset,setOffset] = useState(0)
const [limit,setLimit] = useState(3)
...and so on
```

Comment: thanks, I am looking into it, sounds promising ! That doesn't exactly answer my question though

Comment: added the usage of useEffect and parentcallback @DevMoutarde

Comment: ah thank you very much, will get back to you asap, I am trying a different way right now

Comment: should I wrap the useEffect function around the whole code then ? Otherwise my variables aren't accessible to the rest of the function component ? Is it common practice ?

Comment: const [offset,setOffset] = useState(0) is supposed to be in place of let variables = {}.

Comment: please refer this example for useEffect usage https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: yeah I get that, I was talking about, the return of my API call, that I need into my child component. But I cannot put react JSX elements in useEffect so I'm a bit confused on how to pass variables to the JSX return

Comment: All of this actually relies on memo right ? Because otherwise, using states in the parent component, everything will re render every time. But I am not sure memo is the right way to go...

Comment: The components you want to restrict re-rendering should be wrapped in memo. and the other component which requires data should be passed as props. inside useEffect you can store the response inside state so that on the next render the C2 component will get the latest data. and C1(Memoised component ) will not get re-rendered

Comment: Yeah so if I choose not to use memo (because as I said, I am not sure at all this is the way to do it, more like a workaround), it won't work as expected.. also, I cannot use my useQuery hook in useEffect, that is a problem....

Comment: Let me think if I can get any other way to do it

Comment: I got a solution, I believe. I now understand how useEffect deps argument works. I ll get back to you soon, I am very tired lol thank you very much for all of this anyway

Comment: Hello, I tried wrapping my <Sideinfo> with memo but the whole component still renders when I useState, is it expected ? the whole page reloads...